# How to strip leading whitespaces from an offset of a string array in Python?

Tags: python, string, removing-whitespace

I'm new to Python, but I had a simple question.  I know that I can use lstrip() to strip leading whitespaces/tabs from a string.  But lets say I have a string str:

```
str = '+        12  3'
```

I want the result to be

```
'+12 3'
```

I wanted to achieve this by calling lstrip on a substring of the original string:

```
str[1:] = str[1:].lstrip()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex.py", line 51, in <module>
print(Solution().myAtoi('    12  3'))
File "ex.py", line 35, in myAtoi
str[x:] = str[x:].lstrip()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there a way to achieve this using lstrip()? Or should I look into another way of doing this?

For the record, this is just a leetcode practice problem, and I'm attempting to write it in Python to teach myself - some friends say its worth learning

Thanks! :D

Comment: Since you are new, you should know that Python strings are immutable, hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `str.lstrip` on the part of the string *before* the `+`, then concatenate the first character back:

```
>>> s = '+        12  3'
>>> s = s[0] + s[1:].lstrip()
>>> s
'+12  3'
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry for getting back so late. Went to bed. This was a nice surprise in the morning though ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

data = re.sub("(?<=\+)\s+", '', '+        12  3')
```

Output:

```
'+12  3'
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=\+) #is a positive look-behind
\s+ #will match all occurrences of white space unit a different character is spotted.
```

Comment: Ah, nice I was getting ready to add a regex solution to my answer as well, but this ones cleaner. +1

Answer (score 1):

`str` is an immutable type.  You *cannot* change the existing string in place.  You *can* build a new string and reassign the variable handle (by name).  `Christian` already gave you the details of building the string you want.